# New data only appears after a page reload- AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a small problem here. When I add a new data via a form, it is not displayed/fetched until page reloads. For Page reload, I'm using `$state.reload()`, as follows:

```js
.then(function () {
          $state.reload();
        });
```

If I remove it(`$state.reload()`), data won't be displayed until I do manual reload of the browser. Which technique can I use in the promise so that after new data is added, it get displayed without reloading page? Thanks.

Comment: How are you displaying the data? Could be as simple as a `.apply()`

Comment: In the view, I'm using `ng-repeat` to loop through data. I'm displaying the data in a drop-down menu. Though your question isn't clear.

Comment: What scope var are you repeating? is that scope var updated after you get data? Did you try using apply() after the data is refreshed?

Comment: I haven't tried `apply()`. The scope variable is not updated when new data is added.

Comment: Perhaps you should add more code, from the code you pasted there isn't a way to determine what is wrong

Comment: Try adding $scope.$apply() after you get the new data as suggested by @Huangism

Answer (score 0):

You should read response from the call back.

```
.then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
    });
```

> get the data from "response" and bind it with the model.